# Internet Explorer 10: <audio> "play" Event Handler Occurs Only Once?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, html5-audio

Here is a simple test ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rcjjq/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Audio Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('audio_test').play();">Play Audio</a>

        <audio id="audio_test" onplay="javascript:console.log('played');" onended="javascript:console.log('ended');">
            <source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            <source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using the above code and playing the audio file multiple times, Internet Explorer 10 only runs `console.log('played');` once. Is this behavior intended by Microsoft or am I doing something wrong? Is there a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current spec says that the precondition for the `play` event being fired is that "*`paused` is newly false*"

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-play

So, that probably means it only fires on the first time, and after switching from the paused state. You could try calling `audioElement.pause()` on `ended`

```
onended="javascript:this.paused(); console.log('ended');
```

So while this seems to fix the problem, it might not be an applicable workaround depending on your needs. In that case maybe you could utilize the [`playing` event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-playing).